# Can I continue vaccines in France? (from the US)

Tags: usa, france, health

I'm about to leave to France this weekend, and just this week I had an incident that now requires a series of vaccines, some of the dates in the series will fall while I'm in France, in two different cities. It's for rabies, so I know the vaccine is commonly available and is the same strength and so on.

Has anyone had to continue a series of vaccines from one country into the next? Has anyone done this in France? I'm wondering about the paperwork required, and if you need an appointment?

Comment: I think this is likely to vary a lot depending on what country you're going to, so we may well need to make this question France-specific to fit within our format of Q&A. (We don't really want a list of 50 different answers, one for each country...)

Comment: Right on, I'll edit the title, anything else?

Comment: @pnuts That question was about preventative vaccinations this is a required one for post-exposure.

Comment: Possibly Related (on Expats): [How to find an English-speaking general practitioner in France?](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/864/120)

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr, I boned up on my vocabulary, and it made everything smoother. Everything started in French, and ended in English and it went just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I will let another person answer for how to get an appointment in France. I would however advise to log,you current vaccination on a [International certificate of vaccination](http://www.who.int/ihr/ports_airports/icvp/en/) . This would give you the details of your vacination in an international standard format.

If you arrive in France through charles de gaulle or orly airport you could contact the travel clinic for advice. They will probably be able to give you details on what is possible

Comment: Thank you! I did as you suggested. The travel clinic in CdG gave me the contact information for the best places in the cities I was visiting, and through email I was able to explain my situation before I arrived at the clinics. Having the box from original vaccines plus the international certificate was all I really needed. I also kept the vaccine boxes and all paperwork in order that my GP at home could enter everything in properly into my record.